# How to determine matrix of a linear transformation from $R^{n,m}$ to R^{n,m}

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, transformation

I know how to determine a matrix for a transformation from $R^n$ to $R^m$ but I am not sure how to do it for space of matrices. I know the size of the matrix should be $m\cdot n\times m \cdot n$, but what should be in each column?

Comment: you need first to set a basis of the matrix space, an then try to write the image of the basis on the columns of your $mn\times mn$ matrix

Comment: @Joelia See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3774803/81360) for an example

Comment: @Joelia Did you have a specific transformation in mind?

Comment: As others have said, if you know how to generate $A$ given the standard basis $I_n$, the same algorithm will allow you to generate a matrix for a transformation from arbitrary vector spaces $V \rightarrow W$.

Comment: Thank you all! The example that @BenGrossmann sent helped me